# Is my async websocket python code correct?

Tags: python, async-await, websocket

This is the first time I am posting here, so please go easy on me : ).

I am also writing for the first time python code which uses `async` / `await` for streaming web-socket information.

My main goal is to:

1. Connect to a web-socket
2. Stream info from web-socket
3. Continuously save the streaming info somewhere (to DB for example).

My main concerns are:

1. Whether the code below is streaming information from a web-socket correctly - to be clear: the code is working, but I am not 100% certain it's doing what I want it to do, albeit showing results as expected. There's a lot happening under the hood, hence my concern.
2. Whether it's also closing the connection to the web-socket.
3. How to wrap a function over it (i.e. the function that save the data somewhere).

If you see other problems with it, please let me know.

```
msg = {'message': 'subscribe'}

async def stream_websocket_info():
    async with websockets.connect(WEBSOCKET_URL) as websocket:
        await websocket.send(json.dumps(MESSAGE))
        while True:
            print(await websocket.recv())

# This is how I run it:
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(stream_websocket_info())
```

Comment: So is this code working? *Whether the code below is streaming information from a web-socket correctly* seems to allude that it isn't working.

Comment: The code is working and as an event occurs in the server, the client prints it. But since I am doing this for the first time and sine it's a convoluted subject, I wonder whether I am doing this right and what are potential places which may be future technical debt if I can say so.